# Light and dark theme Flutter

Tags: flutter, themes

Hey guys I'm fairly new to Flutter and I'm trying to add a function that can switch the theme in my app from light to dark and visa versa, but I can't seem to get it right. I followed a tutorial from Aditya Thakur: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roCaIr2X5og. He works with the demo-code, I think that's where my problem comes in. Hope you can help!

This is my code:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bachelorproef/pages/Home.dart';
import 'package:bachelorproef/pages/Loading.dart';
import 'package:bachelorproef/pages/Categorie.dart';
import 'package:bachelorproef/pages/Verwijderde_Items.dart';
import 'package:bachelorproef/pages/Email.dart';
import 'package:bachelorproef/pages/Kabels.dart';
import 'package:bachelorproef/pages/Bestanden_Openen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:bachelorproef/theme_model.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => Home(), //Loading() verwijst naar loadingpage
    //'/Home': (context) => Home(),
    '/Categorie': (context) => Categorie(),
    '/Verwijderde_Items': (context) => Verwijderde_Items(),
    '/Email': (context) => Email(),
    '/Kabels': (context) => Kabels(),
    '/Bestanden_Openen': (context) => Bestanden_Openen(),
  },
  //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roCaIr2X5og  tutorial
));

void theme() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ThemeModel(),
      child: Consumer(
          builder:(context, ThemeModel themeNotifier, child){
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: themeNotifier.isDark ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
              home: Home(),
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Home.dart**

```
import 'package:bachelorproef/theme_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:bachelorproef/main.dart';




class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer( builder: (context, ThemeModel themeNotifier, child) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
          title: Text('EHBC - Eerste Hulp Bij Computers',
          style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          )),
          centerTitle: true,

          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                themeNotifier.isDark
                    ? themeNotifier.isDark = false
                    : themeNotifier.isDark = true;
              },
              icon: Icon(themeNotifier.isDark
                ? Icons.nightlight_round
                : Icons.wb_sunny
              )
            )
          ],

        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: ListView( //was eerst Column
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.visibility_outlined,
                  color: Colors.grey[600],
                ),
                label: Text(
                  'Lichte modus',
                  style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

          Card(
            color: Colors.blue[300],
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Verwijderde_Items');
              },
              title: Text('Verwijderde items'),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/prullenbak.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Card(
            color: Colors.grey[350],
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Email');
              },
              title: Text('E-mail problemen'),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/email.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Card(
            color: Colors.grey[350],
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Kabels');
              },
              title: Text('Kabels'),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/kabels.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Card(
            color: Colors.grey[350],
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Bestanden_Openen');
              },
              title: Text('Bestanden willen niet openen'),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/folder.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    });
  }
}
```

**theme_model.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:bachelorproef/theme_preferences.dart';

class ThemeModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isDark = false;
  ThemePreferences _preferences = ThemePreferences ();
  bool get isDark => _isDark;

  ThemeModel() {
    _isDark = false;
    _preferences = ThemePreferences();
    getPreferences();
  }

  getPreferences() async {
    _isDark = await _preferences.getTheme();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set isDark(bool value) {
    _isDark = value;
    _preferences.setTheme(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**theme_preferences.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class ThemePreferences {
  static const PREF_KEY = 'pref_key';

  setTheme(bool value) async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setBool(PREF_KEY, value);
  }

  getTheme() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return sharedPreferences.getBool(PREF_KEY) ?? false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had tried your code and understood why the colors doesn't change.

Let's consider a scenario. You have a `Scaffold` and want its background color to change with theme. What are the things you do?

```dart
// first.dart
themeData: isDarkTheme ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
...
Scaffold(
    // don't put any background color
);
```

```dart
// second.dart
themeData: isDarkTheme ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
...
Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: isDarkTheme ? Colors.grey : Colors.white,
);
```

```dart
// third
themeData: isDarkTheme ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
...
Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white, // this doesn't work
);
```

Consider the above three types. the first and second works. But, the third doesn't work. It is because the `backgroundColor` is overriden to white always.

In your code also, you have a lot's of things similar to these which are overriding the `color` given by `ThemeData` or you are not handling the colors properly according to the theme.

So, your Answer is:
Change all the widget color properties either to default or handle it with your own colors using a variable (which you get from provider) -> `themeNotifier.isDark` in your case

**Bonus:**

Below is something which I tried in dartpad (without shared prefs)

What I did?

1. Comment out all color properties
2. commented out shared prefs (you don't need to)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ThemeModel(),
      child: Consumer(
          builder:(context, ThemeModel themeNotifier, child){
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: themeNotifier.isDark ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
              home: Home(),
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer( builder: (context, ThemeModel themeNotifier, child) {
      return Scaffold(
//         backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
//           backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
          title: Text('EHBC - Eerste Hulp Bij Computers',
          style: TextStyle(
//           color: Colors.black,
          )),
          centerTitle: true,

          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                themeNotifier.isDark
                    ? themeNotifier.isDark = false
                    : themeNotifier.isDark = true;
              },
              icon: Icon(themeNotifier.isDark
                ? Icons.nightlight_round
                : Icons.wb_sunny
              )
            )
          ],

        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: ListView( //was eerst Column
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.visibility_outlined,
//                   color: Colors.grey[600],
                ),
                label: Text(
                  'Lichte modus',
                  style: TextStyle(
//                   color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

          Card(
//             color: Colors.blue[300],
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Verwijderde_Items');
              },
              title: Text('Verwijderde items'),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/prullenbak.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Card(
//             color: Colors.grey[350],
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Email');
              },
              title: Text('E-mail problemen'),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/email.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Card(
//             color: Colors.grey[350],
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Kabels');
              },
              title: Text('Kabels'),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/kabels.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Card(
//             color: Colors.grey[350],
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Bestanden_Openen');
              },
              title: Text('Bestanden willen niet openen'),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/folder.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    });
  }
}

class ThemeModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isDark = false;
  ThemePreferences _preferences = ThemePreferences ();
  bool get isDark => _isDark;

  ThemeModel() {
    _isDark = false;
    _preferences = ThemePreferences();
    getPreferences();
  }

  getPreferences() async {
    _isDark = await _preferences.getTheme();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set isDark(bool value) {
    _isDark = value;
    _preferences.setTheme(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class ThemePreferences {
  bool darkTheme = false;
//   static const PREF_KEY = 'pref_key';

  setTheme(bool value) {
    darkTheme = value;
//     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
//     sharedPreferences.setBool(PREF_KEY, value);
  }

  getTheme() {
    return darkTheme;
//     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
//     return sharedPreferences.getBool(PREF_KEY) ?? false;
  }
}
```

Working Demo:
[image: Working demo of above code]

Comment: Great! It would be better if you can accept and upvote the answer for others who come here.

Comment: You are amazing. I just solved my app performance issue by removing the backgroundColor properties from the scaffold. 

Thanks